# Is there a way to remove and recreate an Elasticsearch alias atomically?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have some code with a probable race condition in it.

I suspect the problem lies here:

```
if self.es.indices.exists_alias(self.__class__.index_alias):
    old_index_name = (list(self.es.indices.get(self.__class__.index_alias).keys())[0])
    self.es.indices.delete_alias(index=old_index_name, name=self.__class__.index_alias)
self.es.indices.put_alias(index=self.destination_index, name=self.index_alias)
```

It kinda looks like there's a race condition there, if there are other parts of the code looking to update that index via its alias at the same moment.

Is there a way of combining the deletion and recreation (and perhaps the test) into a single ES operation?

I googled a bit, but didn't find anything interesting.

I also tried just put_alias'ing without the delete_alias, and got several errors from the application.  I'll revisit that, though, if folks think that should help.

BTW, the troublesome index is (almost?) always yellow when I inspect the index list using curl.

Thanks!

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/60602968/4039431 this answer explained in detail the cause of yellow status, how to fix it and what is the impact of it, please have a look and let me know if further questions –

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Thanks for the link.  It's actually an inappropriately-created index that's coming up yellow.  There's supposed to be a grok_timeseries alias pointing at grok_timeseries_0001, but instead I get a grok_timeseries index that's yellow.  I'm not sure this is a clue at this point, but if you believe otherwise, please let me know!

Comment: can you tell the no of replicas for `grok_timeseries` and no of data nodes in your cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot the Yellow cluster issue, which can also be a cause of your race-condition you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60602968/4039431) answer.

**Alias link and unlinking can be done in a single API which is atomic**, Please use [rename alias api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases-api-rename-alias-ex) and as you can read:

> Renaming an alias is a simple remove then add operation within the
>   same API. This operation is atomic, no need to worry about a short
>   period of time where the alias does not point to an index:

### Sample

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias2" } }
    ]
}
```

**Note: This API is atomic, hence it would rollback the changes if one operation isn't successful.**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Elasticsearch client in Python to perform atomic update of aliases, please use the `update_aliases` method from ElasticSearch IndicesClient, as in example below:

```
def update_aliases(es_client, indexes_wildcard, index_name, alias_name):
    body = {
        "actions": [
            {"remove": {"index": indexes_wildcard, "alias": alias_name}},
            {"add": {"index": index_name, "alias": alias_name}}
        ]
    }
    es_client.indices.update_aliases(body)
```

Please refer to Elasticsearch Python library [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.11.0/api.html?highlight=update_aliases#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.update_aliases)